# Event key for "TAB" and "TAB + shift" on add-on modal?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, development

I am finalizing a Blender add-on and I have an issue on the modal part with 2 events triggered by <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

Here is the actual code:

```
# TAB event
elif event.type == "TAB" and event.value == "PRESS":
    ...
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

# TAB + SHIFT event
elif event.type == "TAB" and event.shift and event.value == "PRESS":
    ...
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

The first event `TAB` works perfectly but the second event `TAB + SHIFT` does not work at all (never triggered).

So, without any success, I tried to:

1. group the event condition such as: `( event.type == "TAB" and event.shift ) and event.value == "PRESS"`
2. replace `event.shift` by `event.type == "LEFT_SHIFT"`
3. remove `event.value == "PRESS"`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a correct solution using a better code semantic.

The code should be done in 2 nested conditions; the main `TAB` event and the `SHIFT` event as in the following code:

```
elif event.type == "TAB" and event.value == "PRESS":

    if event.shift:
        # ... (code for TAB + SHIFT)
    else:
        # ... (code for TAB)

    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

A second good solution, closer to the initial code, consists to put the `TAB + SHIFT` condition first (thanks to [batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger)).

```
# TAB + SHIFT event -FIRST-
elif event.type == "TAB" and event.shift and event.value == "PRESS":
    ...
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

# TAB event
elif event.type == "TAB" and event.value == "PRESS":
    ...
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

Hope that could help someone else!

Comment: The logic was wrong. Your answer has the logic right.  (Not sure re the correct, better or way it _should_ be done), Could  have  simply changed the order of your elifs in "actual" question code, or nest the other way ie have shift in outside if.

Comment: Yes, changing the order of the 2 elifs is a good way too. First "TAB + SHIFT" and second "TAB" - in my initial code, the first "TAB" condition was always triggered and was blocking the second condition. Let me edit the answer to add you solution!